# mySql Select last entry for each user

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables:

```
users:
user_id    user_name

data:
user_id    user_data    user_time
```

I wan to select the latest entry from the data table, but return the `user_name, user_id, user_data` and `user_time`.

I have tried the following query, but it returns the **first** entry, not the last for each user:

```
sql = "SELECT users.user_name, users.user_id, data.user_data, data.user_time
FROM users 
INNER JOIN data ON data.user_id = users.user_id
GROUP BY users.user_name
ORDER BY data.user_time DESC";
```

Comment: if desc is giving you the wrong end then asc is probably the answer

Comment: What is the column type and format of data.user_time?

Comment: Please...guys...read the question. I want the LATEST entry for each user. The query returns the FIRST entry. I do want the returned results sorted by DESC as it is now. I just want the LATEST entries.

Comment: @trickyzter: it is an integer, user_time is in miliseconds.

Comment: last may or may not be latest, bye :-)

Comment: Sorry about being snippy. But two people already offered suggestions which apparently have nothing to do with the question being asked.

Comment: Sam, please be patient and show my answer. May be it solves

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use GROUP BY and MAX, WHERE...IN:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.user_name, d.user_data, d.user_time
FROM users u
    INNER JOIN data d ON d.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE (d.user_id, d.user_time) = 
    (SELECT user_id, MAX(user_time) FROM data GROUP BY user_id)
```

I think you had better add `data_id` column to data table.
Unless data_id, both user_id and user_time are necessary for `PRIMARY KEY`(and user_time is not always unique, not reliable)

If there is data_id, it can be bitly simple:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.user_name, d.user_data, d.user_time
FROM users u
  INNER JOIN data d ON d.data_id =
    (SELECT data_id FROM data
       WHERE user_id = u.user_id ORDER BY data_time DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Nice! The sub-query provides the latest, the WHERE selects it, the rest of the query pulls the data. I like it!

Comment: thanks Malovich but It's too late;==) I just edit my code and show another better solution

Comment: @tosin: why do you say that a compound Primary Key is not reliable?

Comment: @ypercube thanks for comment. I mean user_time is not always unique. If primary key is combination of user_id and user_time, I think it's not safe.

Comment: @tosin: OK then. In the mean time, your second query can be written as `... ON (d.user_id, d.data_time) = (SELECT user_id, data_time FROM data WHERE ...`   (everything else unchanged)

Comment: And an index on `(user_id, data_time)` would help improve performance a lot.

Comment: @ypercube Oops, it's sure. I just fixed my code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @tosin: Thank you very much for this answer, you saved me so many headaches!
The `data_id` version is the one that works best